# Неправильный синтаксис около ключевого слово PROCEDURE. Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@JobTitle"

Tags: visual-studio, переменные

Прошу помочь в объявлении скалярного переменного - `@JobTitle`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure2
    /*
    (
    @parameter1 int = 5,
    @parameter2 datatype OUTPUT
    )
    */
AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    RETURN
    ALTER PROCEDURE GetJobTitle
str JobTitle,
@PersonID int,
@JobTitle char(10) output
AS
    SELECT @JobTitle = JobTitle from kts_personaldata 
    where PersonID = @PersonID
```